# Perl - Stop reading a file if multiple lines match

Tags: perl, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I break out of a loop in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303216/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-perl)

I have data that looks like what you see bellow.  I am trying to create a perl script that will capture selected text.  My idea of going about it was saying "if the previous line read was all -'s and the current line read is all ='s then stop reading the file and don't print those lines with only ='s and -'s.

However, I don't know how to code that.  I only started using perl 3 days ago.  I don't know if that is the best way of doing it.  Let me know if there is a better way.
Either way if you could help with the code, I'd appreciate it.

My code so far:

```
...
$end_section_flag = "true" # I was going to use this to signify 
                           # when I want to stop reading
                           # ie. when I reached the end of the
                           # data I want to capture

while (<$in-fh>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;

    if ($line eq $string)
    {
        print "Found it\n";
        $end_section_flag = "false";
    }

    if ($end_section_flag eq "false" )
    {
        print $out-fh "$line\n";
        // if you found the end of the section i'm reading
        // don't pring the -'s and ='s and exit
    }
}
```

What my data looks like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
===============================================================================
BLAH BLAH
===============================================================================
asdfsad
fasd
fas
df
asdf
a
\n
\n
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
===============================================================================
BLAH BLAH
===============================================================================
...
```

What I want to capture

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
===============================================================================
BLAH BLAH
===============================================================================
asdfsad
fasd
fas
df
asdf
a
\n
\n
```

Comment: You haven't shown any text in bold.

Comment: [How do I break out of a loop in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303216/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-perl)

Comment: Real world example should help. From your question is not clear what you want achieve. Show: 1.) what you have 2.) and what you want get 3.) into what variable. Your code does not have any condition about the content - the "$end_section_flag" telling nothing yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question

Comment: It's not clear your idea about `-` and `=`.

Comment: I've update my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Line-wise processing is not so suitable because your boundary crosses line endings. Slurp the file whole, then extract the in-between with the match operator.

```
use strictures;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
my $content = read_file 'so11454427.txt', { binmode => ':raw' };
my $boundary = qr'-{79} \R ={79}'msx;
my (@extract) = $content =~ /$boundary (.*?) $boundary/gmsx;
```

Comment: I'm new to Perl, would you mind explaining the code please?
Thanks :)

Comment: I read the file content into a string variable. Then I define the boundary, 79 dashes and some newline and 79 equals. Then I match the boundaries, and that which is in-between, against the content string. I capture the in-between and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

See if this suits your needs:

```
 perl -ne 'm/^---/...m?/---/ and print' file
```

Should you want only the first block, change the delimiter from `/` to `?` thusly:

```
 perl -ne 'm?^---?...m?^---? and print' file
```

See the [range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator discussion.

This will print the range of lines bounded by '---'.  You can redirect the output into a file of your choice using your shell's redirection:

```
perl -ne 'm/^---/...m?/---/ and print' file > myoutput
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. Where does it go? How does it fit in? What is it doing? Sorry, I'm still new to Perl. I'd appreciate clarification.