# Leave callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
          if( some_func() == 0 ) {
                res.send("some_func() returned zero!");
                /* leave function(req, res) */
          } 

          res.send("Everything OK.")

});
```

How would that work in Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [the `return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      if( some_func() == 0 ) {
            res.send("some_func() returned zero!");
            return;
      } 

      res.send("Everything OK.")
});
```

Or just use an `else`:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      if( some_func() == 0 ) {
            res.send("some_func() returned zero!");
      } else {
          res.send("Everything OK.")
      }
});
```

---

**N.B.** [Perl's `last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) is *not* like `return`; [it is analogous to `break`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303216/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-perl) in C-like languages ([C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), etc.), and is used to exiting loops and switches – not functions.