# Perl: Breaking out of foreach loop when last array element is encountered

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl

Perl noob here.  I have a small script (see below) that I'm using to build a MySQL INSERT statement.

```
use strict;

my @records = qw/Record1 Record2 Record3/;

my $insert = "
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
 ";

foreach my $record (@records) {
        $insert .= "('" . $record . "'),\n ";
}

print "$insert\n";
```

Current Output

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
 ('Record1'),
 ('Record2'),
 ('Record3'),
```

I need to know how to break at the last element of the `@records` array and append a `;` instead of `,`

Desired Output

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
 ('Record1'),
 ('Record2'),
 ('Record3');
```

Comment: will you always have three records?

Comment: No this was just a simplified example.  The actual array will come from anyone of a number of different sources and the array length will vary.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303216/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-perl

You can make a call to last;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with `map` and `join`.

```
my @records = qw/Record1 Record2 Record3/;

my $insert = "
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
 ";

$insert .= join ',', map { '(' . $dbh->quote($_) . ')' } @records;
$insert .= ';'; # this line is not needed
```

The [`quote` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#quote) of `$dbh` is better than just putting the stuff into quotes because it handles bad stuff for you. The `map` is not much different from a `foreach` loop, and the `join` will take care of putting the commas in between the elements, and not the last one.

Comment: That definitely appears to be a more elegant solution, however, now I receive the error `Global symbol "$record" requires explicit package name`.  Where is the `$record` variable defined?

Comment: Thanks for fixing @tobyink. I was about to do that.

Comment: I think `$record` should have been `$_`, so have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: The `$insert .= ';';` can be omitted entirely.

Comment: @ikegami true. I put it there explicitly because OP has it in the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

On a related matter, I always try to avoid putting data and sql statements on the same line, thus minimize the risk of sql injection. In perl you have a prepare/execute mechanism available for this:

```
my @records = qw/Record1 Record2 Record3/;
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES ?");

foreach my $record (@records) {
      $sth->execute($record);   
}
```

http://bobby-tables.com/perl.html

Comment: While this is good advice in general, it does not work for this question. OP asks specifically how to get all rows into one `INSERT` statement. For a very large amount of data that has severe performance implications, because we have one transaction versus a lot. `prepare` internally uses `quote` on each `?` value, and that's what needs to be done if the number of columns (or rows) is variable.