# Perl oneliner: print first lines into file

Tags: windows, perl, shell, cmd

I want to print the first 10 lines of a huge file into a new file. With this oneliner I can print the lines on the monitor:

```
> perl -ne "print if $. < 10" in.csv
```

I tried this:

```
> perl -ne "print if $. < 10" in.csv >out.txt
```

But this does only create the file out.txt without writing the first lines into it. What is wrong with this code?
Thanks for help

---

Windows 7 / Strawberry Perl

---

Update1:
If I send the print result on monitor using:

```
> perl -ne "print if $. <= 10" in.csv
```

the program does not stop, that is, the first ten lines are output on the monitor but it does not end with:

```
>
```

I have to stop the program using Ctrl+c.

Using the simple csv-File like ikegami (just some rows) the onliner works. I assume there is something within the csv-file.

Update 2:
The original onliner:

```
> perl -ne "print if $. <= 10" in.csv >out.txt
```

works. I have to wait some seconds. The csv-file is 2 GB large. The onliner:

```
> perl -pe "exit if $. > 10" in.csv >out.txt
```

gives the result immediately. Conclusion: the first onliner goes through all rows, the second exit after 10 rows.

Sorry that I bother you with this problem. I learnt my lesson: use an appropriate onliner or wait some more seconds.

Comment: This is a MSWin cmd.exe question, not a Perl one.

Comment: It works for me as-is on win2k8r2. Is the output file being set to read-only after its initial creation?

Comment: @stevieb. No. It can be written. I tried the example of ikegami and it works. Obviously, it has something to do with the original csv-file.

Comment: To all: see my answer in Update 2.

Answer (score 2):

hum? That's correct (except `< 10` should be `<= 10`):

```
>type in.csv
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
...
z

>perl -ne "print if $. <= 10" in.csv >out.txt

>type out.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j

>
```

A faster solution would exit when it has no more to print rather than printing the entire file.

```
perl -pe"last if $. > 10" in.csv >out.txt
```

Comment: Probably no point continuing to read and discard the extra lines. How about: `perl -pe "exit if $. > 10"` ?

Comment: Good tip. Personally, I'd use `last`.

Comment: @Grant McLean Thanks!! This does work with my csv-file. Maybe you have an idea why this oneliner works and the other does not using the original file? If you put your answer as **answer** I will give you a point.

Comment: To all: see my answer in Update 2.