# What does "last" do in Perl?

Tags: perl

In the code below, what does `last` do in the while loop? I get that if the `$matrix[$i][$j]{pointer}` variable equals `"none"` it calls `last` but what does it do?

Also why does the $matrix variable include score and pointer using curly braces? `{score}`, I read this as the 3rd dimension in an array, but is this something else? Couldn't find anything on google about this. Thanks!

```
my @matrix;
$matrix[0][0]{score}   = 0;
$matrix[0][0]{pointer} = "none";
#populate $matrix with more stuff

while (1) {
  last if $matrix[$i][$j]{pointer} eq "none"; #<-what is this "last" doing?
  #do some more stuff here
}
```

Comment: It's not Python. I think it's Perl.

Comment: makes sense why my googling wasnt working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Available uses for `last` command:

- last LABEL
- last EXPR
- last

According to Perl's [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html):

> The `last` command is like the `break` statement in C (as used in
>   loops); it immediately exits the loop in question. If the LABEL is
>   omitted, the command refers to the innermost enclosing loop. The last
>   EXPR form, available starting in Perl 5.18.0, allows a label name to
>   be computed at run time, and is otherwise identical to last LABEL .
>   The continue block, if any, is not executed:

```
 LINE: while (<STDIN>) {
        last LINE if /^$/;  # exit when done with header
        #...
    }
```

> last cannot be used to exit a block that returns a value such as eval
>   {} , sub {} , or do {} , and should not be used to exit a grep or map
>   operation. Note that a block by itself is semantically identical to a
>   loop that executes once. Thus last can be used to effect an early exit
>   out of such a block.

Answer (score 12):

You have an answer, about `last` but I thought I'd share this image which illustrates how `next`, `last` and `redo` affect logic flow in Perl loops:

[image]

A `continue` block can optionally be added to a loop to define some statements which will be run on each iteration before looping back up to the top to re-evaluate the loop condition. If there is no `continue` block, `next` will go straight back up to the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already gotten an answer about `last`, I'll address the second part of your question.  Perl has arrays and hash tables (also known as dictionaries).  `@matrix` at the top level is an array, but then its being initialized with another array, and the element in that second array is being initialized with a hash table.

If you used Data::Dumper to print this out, or exported it as JSON you'd see something like:

```
@matrix= [ 
  [
    { score => 0,
      pointer => 'none'
    }
  ]
] ;
```